# how to execute function from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id='dgok' data-fn="delbanner('banners')">OK</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#dgok').click(function(){
    let fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    console.log(fn) // delbanner('banners')
    fn();
});
```

**Error:**

`Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function`

How to execute `delbanner('banners')` in this scenario (clicking on `dgok`)?

Comment: What is 'banners' here? Please post the complete question with proper code in context.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta, `banners` is an argument of the function.

Comment: You can use `eval`, but it's not a great idea. Why do you need to pass functions around in `data-` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding `eval` you may try an approach based on accessing functions via some container (`window` for example):

```
const fnContainer = window;
$('#dgok').click(function(){
    const fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    const fnName = fn.substring(0, fn.indexOf('(')); // 'delbanner'
    const fnArg = fn.substring(fn.indexOf('(') + 2, fn.length - 2); // 'banners'
    if (typeof fnContainer[fnName] === 'function') {
      fnContainer[fnName].apply(fnContainer, [fnArg]); // window[fnName](fnArg);
    }
});
```

Here I assume that your function is defined on `window` and has 1 string argument.

---

Having function argument in a separate data-attribute the approach may look a bit simplier

```
const fnContainer = window;
$('#dgok').click(function(){
    const fnName = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    const fnArg = $(this).attr('data-arg');
    if (typeof fnContainer[fnName] === 'function') {
      fnContainer[fnName].apply(fnContainer, [fnArg]); // window[fnName](fnArg);
    }
});
```

Comment: it seems ok. what if I have argument in separate data attribute - `<div id='dgok' data-fn="delbanner" data-arg='banners'>OK</div>`

Answer (score 1):

this error is correct fn is not function .

use this

```
$('#dgok').click(function(){
    let fn = () => $(this).attr('data-fn');
    console.log(fn) // delbanner('banners')
    fn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use eval but it's never a good idea. EVER

```
let fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
eval(fn) // since fn is a string. it will evaluate whatever is in that string
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/eval

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `eval(fn)` to treat that as a function call:

```js
$('#dgok').click(function(){
    let fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    console.log(fn) // delbanner('banners')
    eval(fn);
});

function delbanner(param){
  console.log(param);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dgok' data-fn="delbanner('banners')">OK</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use **eval**.

Try this: :)

```
$('#dgok').click(function(){
    let fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    console.log(fn); 
    eval(fn);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```js
function delbanner() {
  console.log('m')
}
$('#dgok').click(function() {
  console.log('a')
  let fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
  eval(fn);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dgok' data-fn="delbanner('banners')">OK</div>
```